# Why does MariaDB create another key for this column when it is already part of the primary key?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, foreign-key, primary-key

```
create table foo (
  id int primary key
);

create table bar (
  a int references foo(id),
  b int references foo(id),
  primary key (a, b)
);

show index from bar;

+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| bar   |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | a           | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| bar   |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | b           | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| bar   |          1 | b        |            1 | b           | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=ebd524aa5702fd8c75ef140e5e9264ea

Where does the additional key on b come from? Is this a bug? This does not happen when using MySQL.

Comment: Just a guess, if you delete something from foo it has to check if there is a b in bar that references it. There is no need to do anything for a since the primary key can be used for that. MySQL/MARIADB use of the word key is confusing, index would have been a better word.

Comment: Checking your fiddle, this behaviour starts with 10.5.  You may see the same in a later version of MYSQL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unique constraint replaces existing foreign key](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/310406/unique-constraint-replaces-existing-foreign-key)

Comment: @Lennart I'm not sure how composite primary keys are implemented. Can the primary key be used to lookup values of just "a" because "a" comes first in the primary key? If that's the case, then the additional key/index on "b" makes sense. I tried swapping the columns in the primary key which causes Maria to create an additional key/index on "a" instead, which supports this theory.

Comment: @mustaccio it's related but doesn't really answer the question. He is kinda asking the opposite ;)

Comment: The quote from the manual (in the answer to the dupe) explains the behaviour.

Comment: Primary keys (in all DBMS Im aware of) is implemented via unique indexes. You can efficiently use index (a, b, c) to locate a, a and b but not b or c alone

Comment: I doubt that this doesn't happen in mysql as well. I am pretty sure it does happen there, too, when a Foreign Key is created an index is created as well if there isn't already one covering the FK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `FOREIGN KEY` implicitly creates an index if there is not one already in existence.  The index exists to make the FK constraint efficient to check.

```
PRIMARY KEY(a,b)  -- suffices to provide an index for `a`
INDEX(b)  -- generated by the FK
```

I believe that this has existed in all versions of MySQL and MariaDB when using ENGINE=InnoDB.

Could it be that your 10.5 defaulted to ENGINE=MyISAM?  That Engine ignores FK specifications such as `references(...)`.  Note that the "default engine" has changed over time -- I think InnoDB was the default starting with version 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

The additional index/key is created because the multi-column primary key cannot be used to look up rows when just a "b" is given. See the comments on the question and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html for more info.